# Issue with mqtt client

Tags: python, python-2.7, mqtt, paho

I have below code for mqtt client for receiving message from broker.
If client is disconnected from broker then client tries to connect with broker using `connect()` call again. I have read paho documentation saying that `loop_start()` will handle reconnection with broker. Please let me know if is it right to use `connect()` call for reconnection with broker or let it handle by `loop_start()` itself.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import time

is_connect = False

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("#")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Message received on "+msg.topic)
    parsed_message = json.loads(msg.payload)
    print(json.dumps(parsed_message, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):

    if rc != 0:

        print "Unexpected disconnection." , (rc)
        global is_connect
        is_connect = False
while True:
    global is_connect
    #If client is not connected, initiate connection again 
    if not is_connect:
        try:
            client = mqtt.Client(client_id='testing_purpose', clean_session=False)
            client.loop_stop()
            client.on_connect = on_connect
            client.on_message = on_message
            client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
            client.connect("localhost", 1883, 5)
            is_connect = True
            client.loop_start()
            time.sleep(15)
        except Exception as err:
            is_connect = False


# Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
# handles reconnecting.
# Other loop*() functions are available that give a threaded interface and a
# manual interface.
#client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: There doesn't seam to be an actual question here. Have you tried this code to see what happens?

Comment: Having said that, you might want to move the `is_connect = True` to in the `on_connect` method

Comment: @hardillb This code works fine. But I have one doubt that I am creating object of mqtt client  on every disconnect call. Do it will create any issues with mqtt broker. Also i will move is_connect = True to on_connect()

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the Paho client only reconnects if you use the `loop_forever` function.

So rather than tearing down the whole connection you can always use the `reconnect` function to reconnect if you want to have control of the network loop. But the simplest way is to just use the `loop_forever` function as follows:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("#")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Message received on "+msg.topic)
    parsed_message = json.loads(msg.payload)
    print(json.dumps(parsed_message, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        print "Unexpected disconnection." , (rc)

# Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
# handles reconnecting.
# Other loop*() functions are available that give a threaded interface and a
# manual interface.
client = mqtt.Client(client_id='testing_purpose', clean_session=False)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.loop_forever()
```